# Rectangles on a square grid

Tags: combinatorics

[A grid problem!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzDvv.jpg)

[image]
The photo below has a grid of $5 \times 5$, and its is asked to find the number of $1 \times 2$ (in that orientation as shown) without any of them overlapping.
Is there a formula that can be used of plain old drawing them on it work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're misunderstanding the problem. Before you worry about *how many* rectangles it will use, you will need to think about *if it is even possible*.

Note that each rectangle is $2$ by $1$, and so by placing those rectangles, you can only cover an *even number of grid squares*. However, the grid is $5$ by $5$, meaning that it has an odd $25$ squares to cover.

You will never be able to cover the grid with rectangles in that shape. You will always have one left over at the end, because $2$ does not divide $25$ evenly.

Gilles --> Well... in the question, there is nothing mentioning that you shall not go over the bigger rectangle limits :-) Then I guess 13 will be some minimum number (and yes, 1 will cover "outside" the bigger rectangle).

Comment: Unless, of course, *"to completely cover"* does not exclude going outside the grid, in which case you'd just add the additional tile and have half of it hang outside the grid. No, I'm not trying to be clever here. I'm trying to point out how important it is to convey (if specifying a problem) and understand (if trying to solve a problem) the *boundary conditions*. With respect to this particular question, I simply don't know; *completely* ≢ *exactly*. The cuemath question is, to me, not clear in this respect. If I were forced to guess, I'd side with Nilknarf's answer.